# In Anno 2070, what consumes wood?

Tags: anno-2070

I understand that it's used to buy buildings, but for some reason my stockpile of wood is constantly emptying. Was not able to find any building that should be using it. (Missing 1 Act 3, if that helps at all)

Answer (score 10):

For people who are interested: The ascension of Tier 2 eco houses to Tier 3 costs Wood. If you have it set to "Automatic Ascension" (Top right corner of the stat bar when selecting a city center) then you will constantly lose wood to this.

Hope that helps, and thank you!

Comment: Looks like you ended up with two accounts by accident. I merged them for you, but you might want to consider registering via the link from your profile so that this doesn't happen again and you remain in control of your questions and answers. :)

Comment: @DefaultChar If you were able to solve your own problem, you should accept your own answer.